# Layout Problems with Tkinter

Tags: python, layout, tkinter

I have a problem regarding the layout in tkinter. This is the
[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0k9h.png) I want to have and this is what[I have right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G14K.png)
I am not understanding why this is happening. I thought when I specify the width and height for a specific frame it would take all this place but this is not happening looking at `self.GameStatFrame`. It would be nice if someone could explain to me why code does what it does and what my mistakes were.

Here is the code:

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #self.update_idletasks()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):

        #new frame for everything not in the canvas
        #self.Frame = tk.Frame(self.parent)
         self.MlGameStatFrame = tk.Frame(self.parent, width=600, height=300, 
         bg='blue')
         self.GameStatFrame = tk.Frame(self.MlGameStatFrame, bg='white', 
         width=300, height=300)
         self.MlFrame = tk.Frame(self.MlGameStatFrame,  bg='white', 
         width=300, height=300)


        #self.Frame.pack()
        self.createGraphWidget()
        self.MlGameStatFrame.pack()
        self.GameStatFrame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.W, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.MlFrame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.createGameStats(self.GameStatFrame)
        self.createMlStats(self.MlFrame)
        #self.createLog()


    def createGraphWidget(self):
        self.graph = tk.Canvas(self.parent, background ='white',             
        width=200,height=300)
        self.graph.create_rectangle(0,20,40,50)

        self.graph.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.X)
# needs to get a frame because side by side with Ml stats
    def createGameStats(self,GameFrame):

        Frame1 = tk.Frame(GameFrame, bg='red', width=300)
        tk.Label(Frame1, text="Status: ").pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.YES) 
        #initialize with certain value for now
        self.statusChange = tk.Label(Frame1, 
        text="Learning").pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.YES)

        Frame2=tk.Frame(GameFrame, bg='green')

        tk.Label(Frame2, text="Fitness").pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.YES, 
        anchor=tk.W)    #could get changed
        self.fitnessChange = tk.Label(Frame2, text="6").pack(side=tk.LEFT, 
        expand=tk.YES)

        Frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W)
        Frame2.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.X, anchor=tk.W)


    def createMlStats(self, MlFrame):
        Frame1 = tk.Frame(MlFrame)
        tk.Label(Frame1, text="Status: ").pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.YES)  
    # initialize with certain value for now
        self.statusChange = tk.Label(Frame1,     
        text="Learning").pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X, expand=tk.YES)

        Frame2=tk.Frame(MlFrame)
        tk.Label(Frame2, text="Fitness").pack(expand=tk.YES, anchor=tk.W) 
        self.fitnessChange = tk.Label(Frame2, text="6").pack(side=tk.LEFT, 
        fill=tk.X, expand=tk.YES)

        Frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH,anchor=tk.W)
        Frame2.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()

    root.geometry('600x900-0+0') #120* 50 ppixels in top right corner of desktop
    app = Application(root)

    app.master.title('Sample application')

    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The indentation is incorrect in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .grid layout manager is much more flexible:

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
       self.parent = parent
       Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        graph = Canvas(self.parent, width=200, height=300, bg="white")
        graph.create_rectangle(0, 20, 40, 50)

        mlgamestat_frame = Frame(self.parent, width=600, height=300, bg="blue")
        gamestat_frame = Frame(mlgamestat_frame, width=300, height=300, bg="yellow")
        ml_frame = Frame(mlgamestat_frame, width=300, height=300, bg="green")

        graph.grid(row=0, column=0)
        mlgamestat_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        gamestat_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        ml_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

You can place widgets as if they were in a table. The code above makes your intended layout.

Comment: I wouldn't call `grid` more flexible, just flexible in a different way. It's good for laying things out in a grid, whereas `pack` is best for left-to-right and top-to-bottom layouts. You also made a very common mistake that people make with `grid`, in that you are neglecting to assign a non-zero weight to one or more rows and one or more columns.

Comment: Why do you need to assign a non-zero value to weight? It is to make rows or columns stretchable for resizing or not?